# WP define WP_HOME case all domain show twice in url error

Tags: php, wordpress, url

I added code into `wp-config` file for reducing database request. however, it show all domain twice in domain like:

```
www.abc.com/www.abc.com/wp-content...etc
```

I disabled all plugin but problem still not fixed. if i remove those codes then everything go back to normal.

Does anyone know why？

```
define('WP_SITEURL','www.abc.com')
define('WP_HOME','www.abc.com')
```

Comment: you need to add the code into wp-config file

Comment: improved formatting

Comment: @Deeptichipdey sorry my bad, was meant wp-config :p

Comment: ok, Try adding http:// on both url's